# In PHP, what is the difference between "final static" and "const"?

Tags: php, variables, static, constants

I realize that this question has already been asked elsewhere for different programming languages... But this is not a 100% indicator for the same answer in the PHP domain, so I am asking this question.

Could someone please tell me what, specifically in PHP, is the difference between "final static" and "const" ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### `final`

The **methods** or **classes** can not be modified by a child class. This prevents class inheritance, method-overriding and/or redefinition of methods.

> Only class definitions and/or methods inside a class can be defined as
>   `final`.

### `static`

Declares class **methods** or **properties** as a static value so that you have access to them without instantiating an object. These are shared between parent and child-classes.

> A class definition can not be `static` unlike `final`.

### `const`

These create a constant value for a class. The constant values will get changed and can NOT be changed by a method in either parent or child-class.

> Class constants are allocated per instance of the class.

---

`const` is a type specifier in itself. It can not be put along with `public`/`private`/`static` etc. `final`, as mentioned before can be used along with any method or class definitions and hence; applicable with all of them. `static` can not be applied to class definitions but can be used for class properties.

**UPDATE**

**[modifiers](https://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php) are allowed for class constants since PHP 7.1.0.**

> ```
> class Foo {
>     public const bar = 5;
>     private const baz = 6;
> }
> ```

---

> **To summarise, `final static` can not be used to define something like**:
>
> ```
> class X {
>     final static x = 5;
> }
> ```
>
> which is why you have a `const`.

Comment: In PHP 8.1 `final const` will be allowed.

Answer (score 2):

`final` is not for class properties, only classes and methods. It means that the method cannot be overridden, or that the class cannot be inherited from. `const` is the PHP equivalent to a Java `final` variable.

Answer (score 0):

They don't have anything at all in common, and they create completely different kinds of things. `const` declares a constant. `final static` declares a method which is static (can be called without an instance of the class) and final (can't be overridden by subclasses). `static` alone can be used to define a class-scoped variable, which isn't constant (but variables can't be `final`).